# How to get CentOS 6.5 gui?

Tags: linux, vmware, centos

After, I've installed CentOS 6.5, I just have a terminal with a black background and I can't get gui for it.
Any recommendations?

Comment: Did you install with full or minimal option? What ouput of command `runlevel`?

Comment: I've "CentOS-6.5-x86_64-bin-DVD1" which is more than 4GB. and during installation, I choosed a "Basic Server", and I need gui for it.

Answer (score 2):

Because you chose `Basic Server`, then you need to install GUI for it.

From terminal, type:

```
yum groupinstall Desktop
```

To switch to GUI environment, you type:

```
init 5
```

To edit default runlevel having GUI, you must edit file `/etc/inittab`

Comment: I don't know what runlevel is , as I'm a newbie to the opensource world, but what I've done during installation, is that I choosed it to work as " Basic Server". There were other options like, minimal and Desktop, but I didn't choose them

Answer (score 0):

`init 5` shuts down a server, me not being a linux expert i did this, caused a issue. The server i was working on was remotely hosted and I had a to contact hosting support for them to reboot as i don't have anything like wake on lan setup.
Please change this to a reboot command or place a warning that this will shut down not restart the server 
Thank you

Comment: Since you're talking about CentOS, that statement is simply wrong. `init 5` switches the runlevel to one providing a desktop. `init 6` would be the one to reboot and `init 0` shuts the system down.

Comment: Wish I had the rep to downvote this. For a long time, `init 6` was the recommended way to restart centos in an orderly fashion. Looks like you made a typo.